# Save Product custom filed data to sales_order_item table custom field from in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

I have created custom column in `sales_order_item` table, I am trying to save product custom field data to `sales_order_item` custom filed. But I am unable to save.

tried the way to create field as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order_item" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Order Item">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="custom_message"   nullable="true" comment="Custom Message"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Any suggestions to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my self by adding below code.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="vlc_quote_to_order_item" type="ABCSolutions\SalesOrder\Model\Plugin\Quote\QuoteToOrderItem"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

and save the custom field in the plugin information like below.

```
<?php
namespace ABCSolutions\SalesOrder\Model\Plugin\Quote;

use Closure;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class QuoteToOrderItem
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item
     * @param array $additional
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function aroundConvert(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject,
        Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item,
        $additional = []
    ) {
        /** @var $orderItem \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
        $orderItem = $proceed($item, $additional);
        //$orderItem->setStockMessage('$item->getStockMessage()');

        $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());

        if($_product->getStockMessage() != "In Stock" && $_product->getStockMessage() != "Out of Stock" && $_product->getStockMessage() != "" && $_product->getStockMessage() != null)
            $orderItem->setStockMessage($_product->getStockMessage());

        return $orderItem;
    }

}
```

and finally convert the quote to order item data using **fieldset.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="quote_convert_item">
            <field name="stock_message">
                <aspect name="to_order_item" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `->setCustomMessage($your_value)` in your sales order item save method ?

You might need to use a preference on the class where the save is located and add the set call in the inside.

Comment: Can we have brief ?